# How to get Monday of a week as a number

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the first day of a week in a given year (assuming the week starts on a Monday).

Scenario: The year is 2016. It should return 4, because **Monday** the 4th of January 2016 is the first day of week 1 in 2016.

How would I do that? I want something like this:

```
var date = new Date();
var week = 1;
var year = 2016;
date.getMonday(week, year); // 4 (because 04/01/2016 is a Monday and is week number 1)

week = 5;
date.getMonday(week, year); // 30 (because 30/01/2016 is a Monday and is week number 5)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's `getDay()` method to figure out which day of the week a date object refers to.

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');

var year = 2016;
var firstMonday = new Date(year, 0, 1);  // year, month (zero-index), date

// starting at January 1st, increment the date until a Monday (`getDay() = 1`)
while(firstMonday.getDay() !== 1) {
  firstMonday.setDate(firstMonday.getDate() + 1);
}

// output the date of the first Monday in January
output.value = firstMonday.getDate();
```

```html
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

Comment: Works wonderfully. Why didn't I think of just looping until the first day was a Monday... Damn. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've made a function to solve this... see bellow

```
function getDayInWeek(dayOfWeek, week, year){
   dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek % 7; //ensure day of week
   var baseDate = new Date(year, 0, 1); //get the first day
   var firstDayOfWeek = baseDate.getDay(); //get the first week day
   var inWeek = (week - 1) * 7; //get the days to start of week
   var diff = firstDayOfWeek - dayOfWeek; //get the diff for day in that week
   if(diff < 0) diff += 7;
   baseDate.setDate(inWeek + diff);
   return baseDate.getDate(); //get the month day

}
```

to use specify the week day

```
// 0 = sunday
// 1 = monday
// 2 = tuesday
// 3 = wednesday
// 4 = thursday
// 5 = friday
// 6 = saturday
var firstMonday = getDayInWeek(1, 1, 2016); // the monday in first week of 2016

var mondayOf5 = getDayInWeek(1, 5, 2016); // the monday in 5th week of 2016
```

Comment: I appreciate it, but I feel like it's doing a lot of unnecessary calculations. I'll +1 you just because it works :P

Comment: More generic, but more expensive: /, but solves the problem you choose the week you want

Answer (score 0):

To get ISO-8601 week, which will always be a Monday, see link:
 [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week%20Calculate%20ISO%208601)
 [Calculate ISO 8601](http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/news/view/33796/14863/calculate-iso-8601-week-and-year-in-javascript.html)

```js
function getISOWeek(week, year) {
  var _date = new Date(year, 0, 1 + (week - 1) * 7);
  var date_of_week = _date.getDay();
  var ISOweekStart = _date;
  (date_of_week <= 4) ? ISOweekStart.setDate(_date.getDate() - _date.getDay() + 1): ISOweekStart.setDate(_date.getDate() + 8 - _date.getDay());
  return ISOweekStart;
}
console.log(getISOWeek(10, 2016));
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work though. 1st week of 2019 returns Monday 31st on December **2018**. Also it doesn't return a number.